# Check string format with regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to check a string that comes from an ajax post with php, in particulare the source is a text area with this format:

```
[minute]:[price]
[minute]:[price]
[minute]:[price]
```

Example:

```
10:20
12:22.23
20:30.1
```

And so on, the minutes is an integer and the price could be a float with  0 to 2 decimals(10,  10.0, 10.00 are fine), I'm only able to check them in a simple way: double explode( "\n" and ":") and is_number + float on sub-element, but it looks pretty inconvenient, could someone suggests me an expression to use with `preg_match`?

Comment: Put your attempt first?

Comment: Now that is a good expression `looks pretty inconvenient`, Why not try something fist and ask us why it is not working?

Comment: Ehm...it's a shame, but I don't know almost nothing about regex :(

Comment: This worked for me: `(\d)+:(\d)+(.(\d)+)*` - Check out this website for testing your regex: https://www.debuggex.com/#cheatsheet - I have only just started learning regex so there might be a better one but it worked for your 3 examples.

Comment: @Jessica the string comes from a textarea and I don't know if the new line could influence the regex

Comment: Did you even try it yet?

Comment: @jessica Sorry, I had to finish the function, this is the line: `if(!preg_match('(\d)+:(\d)+(.(\d)+)*',$_POST['ratetable'])){` and this is the error: `Unknown modifier '+'`

Comment: You need to use delimiters (surround the pattern with `/`)

Comment: @Jessica Just tryed: it validate also `10ggggg`

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match(/\d{1,}:\d{1,}([.][0-9]{1,})?/s);
```

Comment: /\d{1,}:\d{1,}(?:\.\d{0,2})?/s

better

Comment: it validates also:  `12:22.23xxxxx `

Comment: This doesn't match `25:12` (price without decimal)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you want:

```
$re = '/[\d]{1,2}\:[\d]{1,2}(?:\.[\d]{1,2})?/m';
$str = "12:22\n12:22.23\n12:22.23";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches); //This catch only correct values

echo "<pre>";
foreach($matches[0] as $value){
  $split = explode(":", $value);
  $minute = intval($split[0]);
  $price = floatval($split[1]);

  echo "minute -> " . $minute . " value -> " . $price . "\n";
}
```

The expression `/[\d]{1,2}\:[\d]{1,2}(?:\.[\d]{1,2})?/m` catch patterns like `12:12.12`. See [Regex101 example](http://regex101.com/r/mF7zX8)

[preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches)](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match-all.php) Perform a global regular expression match and put the matches into the $matches array.

`intval($split[0]);floatval(split[1]);` will ensure that the values are in the correct format.

Comment: Why do you put `\d` in character class?

Comment: M42 did it to refer to any digit caracter. Instead of `[\d]` could be also `[0-9]`

Answer (score 0):

After reading your answers:

```
/^(\d){1,}?\:(\d){1,}(?:\.(\d){1,2})?$/mi
```

and this the complete function:

```
preg_match_all(' /^(\d){1,}?\:(\d){1,}(?:\.(\d){1,2})?$/mi', $_POST['ratetable'], $out);
if($out[0]!=explode("\n",$_POST['ratetable'])){
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode(array(0=>'Invalid price table at line: '.implode(", ", array_diff_key(array_flip(explode("\n",$_POST['ratetable'])),array_flip($out[0])))));
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d+:\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

In:

```
if(preg_match("/^\d+:\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/", $str))
{
    echo "Valid input!";
}
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/bG3xM4)